# Integrating Sphider search engine in to website

Tags: php, sphider

I have Sphider search engine up and running on my site but I am having two problems.

1. I am not clear on how to set up the indexing for the results to properly show up.
2. I am trying to take the search.php file and

   ```
   include ('sphider/search.php');
   ```

   in the dashboard.php file which is located in the root dir of my site.

Sphider is at

```
root/sphider/search.php
```

but when I include it nothing shows up. If anyone has any insight on the issues I am having I would appreciate it. Yes I have found some online documentation here and there but nothing that clears this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

because sphider is not installed in root directory You might need to update some of your path(s) within search.php    eg. add another '../sphider/'  in the path of everything so it can reference required php files etc.  this way can get very complicated and is probably not worth it.

For my site I created a simple flash search box that uses 
URL request of 'search.php?query=' + KeywordVar + '&start=1&search=1&results=10'
Works great.

AS3 Example:

```
var KeywordVar = SearchTextBox01.text;
var URLpart1 = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/search.php?query=';
var URLpart2 = '&start=1&search=1&results=10';
var MySearchLink = URLpart1 + KeywordVar + URLpart2;

MySearchButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,MySearchFunction);


function MySearchFunction(e:Event){navigateToURL(new URLRequest(MySearchLink)); }
```

In your case I would just use a simple form that uses 'get' to the search 'Search.php' file and then
include your header & footer in the Sphider's header & footer Templates.  or create your own header & footers to match your requirements.

HTML Example:

```
<div> 
  <form action="sphider/search.php" method="get"> 
    <input type="text" name="query" id="query" size="40" value=""> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="1"> 
  </form> 
</div>
```